# Setting design in any browser screen size without scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to design a website with html, bootstrap etc. Main critiriea is that in any browser window size the scroll bar donot have to appear. image and other  has to adjust for that. Screen is like:.
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one. You have to use media queries for height, account for popular heights and make the elements for the intermediate height states not overflowing your screen. I suggested you use the following media queries and adjust your elements for each of them accordingly:

```
@media (min-height: 1200px) {
    .banner{ height: 760px; } //example
}

@media (min-height: 1080px) {
    .banner{ height: 600px; } //example
}

@media (min-height: 900px) {
    .banner{ height: 560px; } //example
}

@media (min-height: 800px) {
    .banner{ height: 440px; } //example
}

@media (min-height: 768px) {
    .banner{ height: 400px; } //example
}

@media (min-height: 600px) {
    .banner{ height: 300px; } //example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put **Media Queries** in your **CSS** file. like below

```
@media tv and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ...  }
```

Refferences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try using relative values for height properties in CSS selectors.
For eg:

`#content {height: 77%;}
 #footer {height: 22%;}`

It will force your containers to fit into window size.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's when you can use percent-based dimensions.

In this example I set the header to be 20% of the height, the container 60% and the footer 20%. So it doesn't matter what height my window is, because it's in percent of the height.

Example below:

```css
body,html{
  height: 100%;  
}
header{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="container"></div>
<footer></footer>
```